# @Support query seems inverted

Tags: css, media-queries

I wrote a media query to check if a browser supports scroll-snap and the queries run when the browser does not support it

```
@supports (scroll-snap-type: mandatory ){
    .swipe-layout{
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: flex;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .swipe-layout > div{
        width: 100vw;
        min-width: 100vw;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
    body{
        background-color: green;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct value for [`scroll-snap-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) with the `mandatory` keyword is either `x mandatory`, `y mandatory` or `both mandatory`, but not just `mandatory`.

But note that `scroll-snap-type` was present in an early draft of the specs (Point based vs Element based), now deprecated. Some early implementations did already support this keyword and thus will return a misleading `@support`, even though they don't support the new Element based API.
[Here you can see a table](https://gist.github.com/majido/9900261e1b7e2b1eb180b01c03656b42) of the different stages this API knew.

So instead you should prefer one of the new properties that have been added by the *Element base*, like for instance the `scroll-snap-align` property.

```css
p { color: red; }
@supports( scroll-snap-type: x mandatory ) {
  .scroll-snap-type {
    color: green;
  }
}
@supports( scroll-snap-align: center ) {
  .scroll-snap-align {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="scroll-snap-type">scroll-snap-type</p>
<p class="scroll-snap-align">scroll-snap-align</p>
```